# Why is this loop only printing one side of the pyramid? help pls

Tags: java, nested

I wrote the following code to print a pyramid, but only one side is being printed.

```
int k = 7;
int m = 13;
int x = 6;
int y = x;

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (j < x) System.out.print(" ");
        if ((j >= x) && (j <= y)) System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    x++;
    y++;
}
```

This code should print a pyramid starting with 1 asterisk at the top (first row containing the most spaces) and then increment by 2 each time until a pyramid with 7 rows is formed.

Comment: Bad code, explain to us what `x`, `m`, `y` and `k` represent ? For this kind of problem you would usually need only one variable that will hold number of rows and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize it for you:

```
int k = 7;
int m = 13;
int x = 6;
int y = x;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (j<x)
            System.out.print(" ");
        if (j>=x && j<=y)
            System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    x--;
    y++;
}
```

`x` needs to reduced each loop until the base of the triangle to maintain
 the spaces amount.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `x++;` should be `x--`;

Answer (score 0):

your `x` and `y` are always the same, so this

```
if ((j >= x) && (j <= y))
```

will only be true once, when `j` is exactly = `x` = `y`.